# Не трекается событие в Google Analytics

Tags: httpclient, google-analytics

Я отправляю запрос POST по url https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-151666808-2&cid=123&el=cus&ea=CLIENT_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS3&ec=Server Но оно не трекается в мой ресурс. 
Я отправляю это с Java API. Я использую Rest Template, feingClient, gama-client-core, google-analytics-java библиотеки. Результат всегда один и тот же - событие не отслеживается. Если я изменю tid в запросе на другой, то событие будет отображаться в другом ресурсе. Или, если я вызываю по этой ссылке через POSTMAN, то результат также будет успешным.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках представления необходимо было отключить флаг на  Фильтрация роботов